# Send multiple file attachments to php file using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have the following html code inside a form:

```
<input type="file" id="attachments" name="attachments" multiple>
```

I already have a javascript function that handles the onsubmit for the form using ajax but without handling the uploaded files.

This is the part of my javascript function that sends the data to the required php file:

```
var to_users = $("#to_users").val();            
var title = $("#title").val();
var content = $("#content").val();

var data = {
    to_users:to_users,
    title:title,
    content:content
}

$.ajax({url: "submit.php", type:"POST" , data:data ,success: function(result){

    // does something
}});
```

There are many tutorials and questions online about attachments using ajax and php but none of them handles multiple files.
My question is: what do I need to add to this function so that I send the attached files to the php file ? And what should I write in the php file in order to handle the files it receives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To upload multiple images use array:

```
<input type="file" id="attachments" name="attachments[]" multiple>
```

and send the form data using ajax:

```
 var formData = new FormData(this);
$.ajax({
    url: "submit.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(result){

    // do something
   }
});
```

In php file use a loop( `foreach` i recommend) to save all attachments.

```
foreach($_FILES['attachments']['name'] as $key=>$val){

// do whatever you want

}
```

Comment: it didnt work.. i put in the php code `if(isset($_POST["attachments"])) echo "attached";` but it didnt echo anything

Comment: Use `$_FILES` not `$_POST`

Comment: okay now it worked.... can i now directly insert the attachments into a database using a pdo update query inside the foreach loop ?

Comment: ofcourse, you can. Inside `foreach` loop insert attachments into database and move into folder too.

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a lot of questions that are almost duplicates, but they all suffer from creating a FormData object and then adding fields to it one-by-one … which fails to show how to handle multiple file inputs (and is a long-winded and fragile approach to the problem).

Just pass the form element as the argument to the FormData object instead.

```
var formData = new FormData(document.querySelector("form"));
$.ajax({
    url: "submit.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
});
```